# Versioning Azure Mobile App API (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, api, azure, versioning

I am currently developing the last batch of changes (hopefully) for a software system that includes the following pieces:

1. Azure SQL Server database backend.
2. Azure Mobile App API middleware.
3. iOS/Android clients.

I'd like to know what is the best way to version #2 such that I can keep its API in sync with #3. That is, I'd like v1.0 of the iOS client to only be able to call v1.0 of the Azure API. When I upgrade to v2.0 of the Azure API (trying to keep the same API method names), I'd like v1.0 of the iOS client to still access the API v1.0 and v2.0 of the iOS client to access API v2.0.

Logically, it seems like you could replicate v1.0 into a new v2.0 Mobile App. That has the advantage of keeping everything separate and not needing to change API method names, just the base URL of the Azure SDK's client. But that's obviously practically pretty untenable, especially if you need to service a high customer load. That could lead to some pretty high charges.

I already subfolder my API files, and it doesn't appear that makes any difference to how I need to call them. If I have a `ReallyCoolMethod.js` file, it doesn't seem to matter where it lives, as long as it is a descendant of the `api` folder in the root. I'd like to avoid having something like this:

- v1.0: `ReallyCoolMethod.js`
- v2.0: `ReallyCoolMethod_v2.js`

But is that the best way? Is there a way to do the following?

```
- root
   |-- api
        |-- v1
        |    |-- ReallyCoolMethod.js
        |    
        |-- v2
             |-- ReallyCoolMethod.js
```

If so, how could I route the call from `InvokeAPI` to the correct version?

***Note:*** I am **not** asking about the difference between Azure Mobile Services and Azure Mobile Apps. I know there are some versioning issues involved there, but that is unrelated to my question. My question is about a single Azure Mobile App and different versions of **my** API within that single app container.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The common practice for REST APIs is to include the version in the URI e.g. https://host/api/v1.0/users/123. Maybe you can follow the same convention? Your backend would route to the correct version of the code based on the uri.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the delayed response. Since I'm calling this API through the Azure mobile app SDK, I'm not sure I can control the pathway between `api` and `{whatever}.js`. As it is right now, the folders I have in place for organization seem to not matter when I'm calling an API method. For instance, if I have `https://host/api/Authentication/Login.js`, I just call it with `invokeAPI:"Login"`. So, I think your answer might be right for web applications, but not for my specific usage. But maybe this will point me in the right direction. Thanks!